# It tells me I cannot convert line 19 and 20 bracelets into int

Tags: c++

cannot convert  'brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int' in assignment
as explained above, line 19 and 20, specifically when I described the content of the array, the compiler told me the line above. I know it is a long code, and I will appreciate your answers.
I guess that's as detailed as I could.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class matrix{
private:
  static const int x =3;
  int m1[x][x];
  int m2[x][x];
  int c[x][x];
public:
  matrix(){
     int m1[x][x];
     int m2[x][x];
     int c[x][x];
     c[x][x];

  }
matrix(int m1[x][x], int m2[x][x], int c[x][x]){
  m1[x][x]= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
  m2[x][x]= {{10,11,12},{13,14,15},{16,17,18}};
  c[x][x];
}

  matrix operator+(matrix& m2){

    matrix result;
    for( int i=0; i<x; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
        result.m1[i][j];
        result.m2[i][j];
        result.c[i][j] = result.m1[i][j] + result.m2[i][j];
      }
    }

return result;
  }
  matrix operator-(matrix& m2){
    matrix result;
    for( int i=0; i<x; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
        result.m1[i][j];
        result.m2[i][j];
        result.c[i][j] = result.m1[i][j] - result.m2[i][j];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  matrix operator*(matrix& m2){
    matrix result;
    for( int i=0; i<x; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
        result.m1[i][j];
        result.m2[i][j];
        result.c[i][j] = result.m1[i][j] * result.m2[i][j];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }


  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const matrix& m){
  outs << m<< endl;
  return outs;
}
};
int main(){
matrix m1;
matrix m2;
cout <<m1+m2<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many basic errors in your code. You will probably be better off reading a good C++ book than trying to 'guess' at code and then seeking help to fix that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok but can you at least help me with my problem?

Comment: (1) You can't assign whole arrays with the `=` operator. (2) `m1[x][x]` refers to **one element** of a 2D array. (3) The redeclarations of variables in your default constructor are meaningless. (4), (5), (6) ...

Answer (score 1):

As already said this code is just wrong from top to bottom. It really should be thrown away. Let fix the most basic error. class `matrix` represents a 3x3 matrix. So it should be written like this

```
class matrix
{
private:
    static const int x = 3;
    int elem[x][x]; // the elements of a 3x3 matrix
public:
    ... // more code
};
```

In your version

```
class matrix
{
private:
    static const int x =3;
    int m1[x][x];
    int m2[x][x];
    int c[x][x];
public:
    ... // more code
};
```

the class has **three** different 3x3 matrices. That isn't right.

So throw your code away, start again with class like the one I've written above.

Here's how `operator+` looks with my version of the class

```
matrix operator+(const matrix& m2) {
    matrix result;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++) {
            result.elem[i][j] = elem[i][j] + m2.elem[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do, You have parameters in the constructor and then you are reinitializing them again.

But I can help you with the way to initialize 2d Matix using the initializer list

```
matrix():m1{{1,2}, {3, 4}} ,...{}
```